# What's the best way to manage iPhone (live) photos and videos on PC?

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, photos, video

I've a lot of photos and videos taken on my iPhone. I'll usually copy the files of the photos/videos periodically from my iPhone to my PC. But this method of copying files manually is messy because the filenames of the image stored on iPhone sometimes can get confusing.

I'm copying these files not for restoring them to my iPhone later, but to free up space.

I'm not using the backup feature in iTunes for this because that backup is only an image of the phone and it doesn't let me view the photos.

Is it possible, on a Windows 10 PC, that I can store, transfer and manage photos/videos from my iPhone to PC such that I can view the pictures/videos and recognise the albums in the Photo App on my iPhone?

Also, it will be great if there is a way to somehow organise and preview Live Photos! Live Photos are a pain because they are actually 2 files and it's so easy to just miss out one of them!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the web-based app in Google Play.
2. Go to web.airmore.com
3. Scan the QR code or click the device to build the connection.
4. Choose "Pictures" or "Videos".
   [image: Click buttons]
5. Press "Export"

Comment: This doesn't work for iPhone, does it?

Comment: of course it can. You should have a try.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the best way to manage iPhone photos on PC is not iTunes. iTunes has many problems and it is not convenient to manage files. So I prefer to use a third-party program named **iOSToto**. It is recommended to have a try.